# Concerned about grouting pre-sealed pebble floor

Tags: tile, grout, sealer

I installed pebble tile on my shower floor, but haven't grouted it yet.

I read to pre-seal before grouting, but later read a warning to only apply sealer to the top of the tile and be careful not to let it drip onto the sides.

Too late, because I used a couple coats of "511 Seal and Enhance" sealer and I got some on the sides and edges of the pebble tiles.

I'm worried about the grout not adhering to the pebbles properly and later separating.

What should I do? Any idea going forward?

Comment: I used a couple coats of "511 Seal and Enhance" to seal the pebbles.

Comment: That's good info to provide. It's best, though, to [edit] your post to include it, instead of putting it in the comments - not everyone reads comments, and they can be deleted in the future, meaning the info gets lost.

Comment: You really shouldn't seal natural stone floor tile in a shower. The floor is not waterproof and water will get into the grout or through cracks and leach into the tile from the backside, then it will not be able to escape because the pores on the surface are sealed so it will never dry out

Answer (score 1):

Clean out the joints before grouting. Use a grout saw or abrasive wrapped around a stick to remove any sealer on the sides/edges of the tiles.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a whole lotta cracks and crevices to get between! Will this be effective with a penetrating sealer like the 511 Seal and Enhance product I used? Thanks, again.